# Why won't ChatOllama work with GraphCypherQAChain?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots

I am trying to get a QA Chain that uses mistral to work, but the Chain fails to restrict the LLM to solely use the relationships in the Knowledge Graph (in Neo4j).

The code is:

```
cypher_chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(
    graph=graph,
    cypher_llm=cypher_model,
    qa_llm=qa_model,
    validate_cypher=True,
    verbose=True,
)

query_1 = "Qual é a relação entre a severidade, recuperação e infecção à COVID 19, insuficiência e deficiência de Vitamina D e o uso de protetor solar?"
query_2 = "Trace a relação entre a severidade, recuperação e infecção à COVID 19, insuficiência e deficiência de Vitamina D e o uso de protetor solar trazendo referências bibliográficas conhecidas que suportem a resposta."
query_3 = "Quem é Silvio Santos?"

for question in [query_1, query_2, query_3]:
    answer = cypher_chain.invoke(question)
    print(answer)
```

when I use:

```
qa_model = ChatOllama(model="mistral", temperature=0.0)
```

It yields long answers, which is incorrect for there are no relations that support such argumentation.

When I use:

```
qa_model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.0)
```

It yields no answers, which is expected.

How can I make sense of this behavior?